Howto recognize Vaadin (24) resynchronization in onDetach method?
In my (Vaadin 24.4.10) application some custom Vaadin Components implement onDetach and release/close ressources that have been initialized in the constructor of those components.
This is to release memory early, e.g. when the user switches from one form to another form.
After onDetach everything that happened in the constructor is rolled back and these components have only a very small memory usage.
Unfortunately there is a situation where this leads to a problem:
When Vaadin starts resynchronizing UI by client's request, then ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc calls ui.getInternals().getStateTree().prepareForResync(). And this leads to a call of onDetach and after that to a call of onAttach.
So when a resynchronizing happens, then my custom components have cleaned up themselves and are more or less unusable without re-calling the constructor.
One approach would be to move everything from the constructor to the onAttach method.
Another approach could be that the onDetach implementation recognizes the resync and does not clean up everything (if anything at all).
I think that this approach is a lot less work and risk in my case than moving everything from the constructor to the onAttach method, so I'd like to follow this approach.
The question / problem is: How can the onDetach method recognize that it's in the resync? StateNode.prepareForResync() does not set a flag before it fires the detach listeners.
(A (temporary) workaround would be that I search in the StackTrace for the method prepareForResynch. This is unsafe because in the future the method could be renamed. So I'm looking for a future-safe way of recognizing whether resynchronization is active in the onDetach call.)

Assuming that there are 17 more implementation details inside Vaadin, that want
you to properly use the designated interface for attach/detach: why is moving
the heavy stuff from the c'tor to onAttach not an option?

When the constructor of form A creates components B and C then all three constructors can use the same shared resources (e.g. DB connection or calculated values) and the form constructor can clean up all of these shared resources immediately. They exist for just a short moment.
When A,B and C initialize themselves independently in onAttach, then either the shared resources have to stay in memory or they have to reallocate/recalculate shared stuff for themselves. It could be delayed until a user opens a Details section. This approach needs allocated memory longer or more calculation time.

This topic is also discussed here: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/18443 ("Add flag to tell if DetachEvent happened because of resynchronization #18443")
